# How to pass a powershell script to Windows PowerShell Host in C#?

Tags: c#, powershell

I would like to use the methods of [Windows PowerShell Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/hosting/windows-powershell-host-quickstart?view=powershell-7.2) on C# project (.NETFramework)
I had installed  System.Management.Automation.dll on my project to run the commands of PowerShell on C#.

My goal is pass my ps1 file that contains:

```
$ProcessName = "Notepad"
$Path = "D:\FolderName\data.txt"

$CpuCores = (Get-WMIObject Win32_ComputerSystem).NumberOfLogicalProcessors 
$Samples = (Get-Counter "\Process($Processname*)\% Processor Time").CounterSamples 
$Samples | Select @{Name="CPU %";Expression={[Decimal]::Round(($_.CookedValue / $CpuCores), 2)}} | Out-File -FilePath $Path -Append
```

to a native implementation in C#. This return the CPU usage of a process.
I want to use the PowerShell Object to avoid to have the ps1 file, because I want to write the previous commands on C# using the System.Management.Automation.PowerShell class, example:

```
PowerShell powerShellCommand = PowerShell.Create();
powerShellCommand.AddCommand("Get-WMIObject");
powerShellCommand.AddArgument("Win32_ComputerSystem");
powerShellCommand.AddArgument("NumberOfLogicalProcessors ");
```

Do you have any idea how to transfer it to powershell Object and methods on C#?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. You have a ps file. You'd like to read the file and use the PowerShell api/Object to take a line from the file and execute it - is that correct?

Comment: No need to recreate the script statements with the API, just invoke the script directly: `powerShellCommand.AddScript(@"C:\path\to\script.ps1");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add parameters block (`param()`) to your script and invoke it:

```cs
const string script = @"
    param(
        [string] $ProcessName,
        [string] $Path
    )

    $CpuCores = (Get-WMIObject Win32_ComputerSystem).NumberOfLogicalProcessors
    $Samples = (Get-Counter ""\Process($ProcessName*)\% Processor Time"").CounterSamples
    $Samples |
        Select @{Name=""CPU %"";Expression={[Decimal]::Round(($_.CookedValue / $CpuCores), 2)}} |
        Out-File -FilePath $Path -Append";

PowerShell powerShellCommand = PowerShell.Create();
powerShellCommand
    .AddScript(script)
    .AddParameters(new PSPrimitiveDictionary
    {
        { "ProcessName", "Notepad" },
        { "Path", @"D:\FolderName\data.txt" }
    })
    .Invoke();
```

Comment: Thank you very much Giorgi!, this is what I was looking for! :)